# Linking a TextAd with a particular keyword

Tags: google-ads-api

I am new to adwords, and from the examples I see, it looks like you link a keyword to a particular AdGroup, as opposed to linking a keyword to a particular ad. Is there a way I can link KeyWords to indivdual ads, instead of the group?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not possible. As you say, you have to link keywords to ad groups. However, you can create one ad group with one ad for each keyword.